# Scene Editor: can't specify texture name without @2x

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift-playground, sktexture

I am setting up a test Sprite Kit Scene file (*.sks) that I plan to use with both the iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus. I have two versions of my Spaceman art work called:

- Spaceman@2x.png (50 x 50 pixels, 25 x 25 points)
- Spaceman@3x.png (75 x 75 pixels, 25 x 25 points)

I was hoping that the Scene Editor would let me specify just "Spaceman" and then select the correct images depending on which device I was running (a bit like you do in code where you don't specify the @2x or the .png). But it seems that I have to select the image for the texture by its full name.

I have noticed that if I select "Spaceman@3x.png" it does scale down and display correctly at 25 x 25 points on the iPhone6 but by this measure I don't need to bother with @2x images at all.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, do I use @2x on iPhone6 and @3x on iPhone6 Plus or do I just go with @3x images only and us them for everything?

[image]

Comment: From what I gather the iPhone 6+ uses the 3x. Apple says that the iOS will "choose the right assets". If using 3x in all other devices, I suspect the system has to down sample to make it work which probably adds more work to be done. Take a look at the "Supporting New Screen Scales" section. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW44

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create "Spaceman.png" image of size 25x25 pixels and select it as a texture in the Scene Editor. In that case @2x and @3x will be used automatically on different devices. I don't think that @1x textures will take too much size in your app bundle.

By the way, it looks like a bug that you can manually select @2x and @3x images in the node properties, because in the Media Library all sizes of one texture are merged into one object. I also found out that all images added to the image set must properly named (like "Spaceman@3x.png") and have the same name as Image Set (like "Spaceman"). Otherwise, they won't be loaded. That is not the case with, for example, launch images and icons.

Also when downscaling, the quality of textures becomes lower (although it's not always visible).

Comment: Woo, thats an idea, I will try adding a @1x version to the scene right now.

Comment: Yup that works, after I had remembered that @1x is "Spaceman.png" not "Spaceman@1x.png" :) The only thing I can see now is that you end up looking at pretty low res textures in the editor, especially if your using it for layout / level editing. Have  good day, your help is much appreciated Sir.